# Generate Url during runtime from asp.net mvc controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-futures

I have such a url:

```
www.test.com/MyAreaName/MyControllerName/MyAction?key1=value&key2=value
```

I need a method like:

```
string generatedUrlWithQueryParams = Url.Action<MyController>(x => x.MyAction(MyViewModel));
```

I need to call the above method from a .cs class NOT from razor html file.

How can I do that? I heard of asp.net mvc futures but I can not find the appropriate method or namespace to use that method.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
string url = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `Request` available(*it is available in your controller actions*), you can use the `UrlHelper` class.

```
var urlBuilder = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
var url = urlBuilder .Action("YourAction", new YourViewModel { Age = 44, Code = "Test"});
```

or

```
var url = urlBuilder .Action("YourAction", "YourController",
                                           new YourViewModel { Age = 44, Code = "Test"});
```

Assuming `YourViewModel` has `Age` and `Code` property and you need those as the route values of the generated url.

If you are invoking this code from another class, you may pass the `RequestContext` to that from your controller/action.

Comment: I generate the url in service class which is not aware of MVC. "YourAction" is hardcoded, I do not want that.

Comment: how does the service class know which action method to use for url generation ?

Comment: at the moment the email templates get the created url injected. The url are created by hand... not refactoring safe ;-)